# Ability to migrate linked Excel spreadsheets to MOSS

Tags: excel, 2007

Hi our finance team have multiple links to other spreadsheets within the current file server. We wish to migrate these to Sharepoint to offer them a solution via Extranet. Is this possible? There doesn't seem to be a migration function to relink the spreadsheets easily?

Comment: Can you provide more details on your scenario? Just so that I understand this correctly does your finance team have links to spreadsheets as shortcuts on their desktops, on the SharePoint portal linking back to the spreadsheets location on the file server or have these links been defined in another system?
And also, when you say the team needs access to these files via the Extranet, do you mean that you'd like to migrate them into SharePoint to allow for remote access to these spreadsheets?
Any other useful information on your business scenario is appreciated.

Comment: The scenario is we have multiple linked spreadsheets on the file server we wish to migrate off the file server to document libraries. Unfortunately all the spreadsheets link through UNC path to the file server. I was hoping there was a script or an easy method to convert all these links to Sharepoint paths.

Answer (score 1):

If you are feeling crazy and these are .xlsx files, you could write a program that would traverse through the OpenXML DOM and do a find and replace. Replace `\\server\finance\stuff` with `http://sharepoint/site/subsite/finance/stuff` or where ever you decide to put it. I haven't done that programmatically yet, but I have opened a .xlsx with WinZip and manually edited the XML before. Here is a link to the [Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124) if you need help getting started with that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try mapping a network drive (net use x: \intranet\site\doclib) to the SharePoint Document Library and then using that drive letter consistently across each user. I am not sure if there is a quick way (apart from copy and paste) to relink existing paths to the new one.